# How to transform a python getter method to an elasticsearch query?

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

I would like to translate python  methods to get specific term from a scraped website to an Elasticsearch query.

I am doing an internship, in webscraping and elasticsearch (and other stuff ..) and I am totally new to this field (and to programming in general)

I was given the task of scraping countries codes, and then make queries to get a country code using another country code for example :

the 2 characters country code for Australia is : 'AU'
and it three characters country code is : 'AUS'

So by precising the 'AU', I would like to have 'AUS' code.

For that I have made a scraping to get all the countries list codes, and made a python code to get this result, an example is below:

```
  "took": 84,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 248,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "countries-codes",
        "_type": "event",
        "_id": "Gx_gEGoBP2qGR-HHGMw3",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Albanie",
          "alpha_2": "AL",
          "alpha_3": "ALB",
          "num": "8"
        }
      },
```

```py
    def get_alpha2_by_alpha3(self, alpha_3):
        for element in self.countries_list.get_countries_list():
            if element['alpha_3'] == alpha_3.upper():
                return element['alpha_2']
```

So basically I would like  to translate the above code to an request, and then implement it in a webpage for internal use

Please be as explicit as you can, I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you used default dynamic mappings when indexing your documents, all of your `strings` should have been mapped as both a `text` type and `keyword` type.  Consequently, a simple `term` query on the `keyword` mapping should yield the results you're looking for.

For example, creating an index with default settings is done simply as follows:

`PUT countries-codes`

Indexing a document as provided would look like this:

```
POST countries-codes/event
{
  "name": "Albanie",
  "alpha_2": "AL",
  "alpha_3": "ALB",
  "num": "8"
}
```

Now, we can look at the mapping of our index to see how Elasticsearch mapped the fields internally:

```
GET countries-codes/_mapping
```

Result:

```
{
  "countries-codes" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "event" : {
        "properties" : {
          "alpha_2" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "alpha_3" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "name" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "num" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now we simply do a `term` query against the `keyword` mapping of the 2-character country code, and we will get a document back representing the match (or in the event there is somehow multiple matches, all documents representing those matches):

```
GET countries-codes/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "alpha_2.keyword": "AL"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note this is a filtered query, as you're not interested in scoring.  In short, filter context will be faster than query context, so use it whenever possible. For more information, reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html

This yields the document you posted before as located in the `hits` return array:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "countries-codes",
        "_type" : "event",
        "_id" : "qGDmEWoBqkB-aMRpdfvt",
        "_score" : 0.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Albanie",
          "alpha_2" : "AL",
          "alpha_3" : "ALB",
          "num" : "8"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any terms submitted which have no match would yield an empty hits array.  On the client side, you could parse out just the element you want.  If you had very large documents or a large number of documents being returned, you would want to look into `source filtering` - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html

For example:

```
GET countries-codes/_search
{
  "_source": "alpha_3", 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "alpha_2.keyword": "AL"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the returned hits object, you'll notice only the piece of the result you wanted is returned from the document:

```
"hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "countries-codes",
        "_type" : "event",
        "_id" : "qGDmEWoBqkB-aMRpdfvt",
        "_score" : 0.0,
        "_source" : {
          "alpha_3" : "ALB"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

All examples are shown using Dev Tools / simple API calls.  Since you're using Python, look at the officially maintained Elasticsearch libraries:

Elasticsearch DSL - Built on top of the lower level Elasticsearch-Py - https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Elasticsearch-Py - https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/